# Como limpar o combobox sem perder os items?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Como limpar o *combobox* sem perder os items?

Eu tento limpar a *combobox* no C#, mas ou ela elimina todas as opções ou o selecionado, como faço pra limpar sem perder os items?

Comment: O que é que você quer dizer com "limpar"?

Answer (score 5):

Pra isso você deve setar o selectedIndex para o primeiro valor da sua combo box. No caso seria o index "-1".

Exemplo:

```
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode estar guardando, por exemplo, 20 items do seu *comboBox1* em um vetor e depois você pode apagar os dados contidos no *comboBox1*.

*Declare como variável global*

```
string[] items = new string[20];
```

**Para guardar os dados e apagá-los do *comboBox1***

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    items[i] = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

**Para devolver os dados ao *comboBox1***

```
int i = 0;
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(items[i]);
}
```